# Highcharts xAxis labels formatter callback data empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm new to Highcharts and need to use the xAxis.labels.formatter function to generate labels. The problem is that when the formatter function runs, the data is empty. If I click on the legend the data is loaded and the labels are created correctly. I tried using charts.events.load to call the labelFormatter function but still no luck. I basically need to generate the labels after the series data is loaded and the chart has been rendered.

```
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        events: {
            load: function () {
                console.log(this);
                this.xAxis[0].labelFormatter();
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [],
        labels: {
          formatter: formatVehicleConversionLabels,
          useHTML: true
        }
    },
    ...

  function formatVehicleConversionLabels() {
    //console.log(this);
    var month = this.value;
    var totalConnectedVehiclesValue = null;
    var notificationsValue = null;
    var downloadsValue = null;
    var installationsValue = null;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.chart.series.length; i++) {
      var currentSeries = this.chart.series[i];
      if(currentSeries.name === "Total Connected Vehicles") {
        if(currentSeries.data.length > 0) {
          for(var j = 0; j < currentSeries.data.length; j++) {
            var currentData = currentSeries.data[j];
            if(currentData.category === month) {
              totalConnectedVehiclesValue = currentData.y;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if(currentSeries.name === "Notifications") {
        if(currentSeries.data.length > 0) {
          for(var j = 0; j < currentSeries.data.length; j++) {
            var currentData = currentSeries.data[j];
            if(currentData.category === month) {
              notificationsValue = currentData.y;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if(currentSeries.name === "Downloads") {
        if(currentSeries.data.length > 0) {
          for(var j = 0; j < currentSeries.data.length; j++) {
            var currentData = currentSeries.data[j];
            if(currentData.category === month) {
              downloadsValue = currentData.y;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if(currentSeries.name === "Installations") {
        if(currentSeries.data.length > 0) {
          for(var j = 0; j < currentSeries.data.length; j++) {
            var currentData = currentSeries.data[j];
            if(currentData.category === month) {
              installationsValue = currentData.y;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return '<table class="x-axis"><tr><th>' + this.value + '</th></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>' + totalConnectedVehiclesValue + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>' + notificationsValue + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>' + downloadsValue + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>' + installationsValue + '</td></tr></table';
  }
```

// FIX

This was fixed by adding an array to the options property and using that as the data for the label formatter function.

```
options:{
  labelData: [],
  ...
  angular.forEach(vm.downloadAndInstallationRateChartConfig.options.xAxis.categories, function(d, i) {
        vm.downloadAndInstallationRateChartConfig.options.labelData.push({
          col: d,
          successfulDownloads: successfulDownloadsData[i],
          successfulInstallations: successfulInstallationsData[i]
        });
      });

      function formatDownloadAndInstallationRateLabels() {
        var labelData = null;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.chart.options.labelData.length; i++) {
          if(this.chart.options.labelData[i].col === this.value) {
            labelData = this.chart.options.labelData[i];
          }
        }
        return '<span style="margin-bottom: 20px; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px;">'+this.value+'</span><br />'+
        '<span style="margin-top: 1px; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px;">'+labelData.successfulDownloads+'</span><br />'+
        '<span style="margin-top: 1px; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px;">'+labelData.successfulInstallations+'</span>';
      }
```

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to add an array for the label data to the options property, see above.